# Using UDFs in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Is it possible to use user-defined functions (UDFs) in Entity Framework? Would it be possible to use them through stored procedures and then add them to the model? As far as I know it's only possible to use select stored procedures through Function Imports if they return an entity - correct me if I'm wrong ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can - but it's hardly documented :-(

Here's a [blog post](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/calling-udfs-from-entity-framework-not-what-you-might-have-expected/) by the Queen of Entity Framework - Julia Lerman - describing how it can be done.

For EF4 with .NET 4.0 sometime in the future, MS plans to support UDF's in Entity SQL - e.g. user-defined functions in the EF model - [check this out](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/05/28/entity-sql-user-defined-functions-in-entity-framework-4.aspx). But that's only going to be available once the .NET 4.0 framework and EFv4 is out.

Marc